# Can I make a pineapple upside down cheesecake in a springform pan?

Tags: cake, cheesecake

I'm making a pineapple upside down cheesecake in a springform pan. Will it leak out? I haven't found a recipe for this. Any suggestion I'm going to put a crust just around the edge of the spring pan to possible stop leakage.

Comment: It might leak out. I don't think the crust is would be strong enough. You could possibly make a crust that will work, but when it cooks it may come unattached from the pan and the liquid will leak out. Can you share a picture of your pan? The answer might depend on how wide the edge is.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the pan. If you assemble your pan and put some water in it, does the water leak out? If not, you're certainly fine. If it leaks slowly, then you're probably fine (but put some foil under it when you bake it). If it leaks quickly, then you've got a problem.